# Error when checking array element in Powershell script : unexpected token 'eq'

Tags: powershell

I wish to go through a sharepoint list and if a property (a choice field named Status) is a certain value then change the author of that item.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://site"
$library = $web.Lists["UserInfo"]
$newUser = $web.EnsureUser("user1")
$oldUser = $web.EnsureUser("user2")

foreach ($item in $library.Items)
{
   #$userfield = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web,$item["DocumentAuthorColumnInternalName"].ToString())
   $userfield = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web,$item["Author"].ToString())
   $userfield = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web,$item["Author"].ToString())
   $login = $userfield.User.LoginName
   #if ($login -eq $oldUser.LoginName)
   if ($login -eq $oldUser.LoginName)
   {

#if($item["Status"] eq 'Fully Implemented')
#{
    $item["Author"] = $newUser
        #if you are using default "Author" column, you need to set the following as well:
        $item.Properties["vti_author"] = $newUser.LoginName
        $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion() #this saves changes without incrementing the version
       #}
   }
   $login = $null
}

$web.Dispose();
```

I can get it working but when I reach the line

```
if($item["Status"] eq 'Fully Implemented')
```

It causes an error

> unexpected token 'eq'

Comment: `-eq`, not `eq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you just missed the hyphen in eq? So it should be:

```
if($item["Status"] -eq 'Fully Implemented')
{
}
```